Client not receiving direct messages: Spring Websocket, Stomp
My Front end client is not receiving the messages from the server. Upon subscribing to the chat it needs to receive a message from the server but this is not received. I've tried the client subscribing to /chat and /user/chat but neither work
javascript client:
const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
        
        brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws'
    });

    stompClient.onConnect = (frame) => { 
        //setConnected(true); 
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame); 
        //console.log('/user/queue/specific-user-user' + frame.headers['user-name']);
        stompClient.subscribe('/user/chat', msg => {
            console.log('response: ' + msg);
        }); 
    }; 
    
    stompClient.onWebSocketError = (error) => { 
        console.error('Error with websocket', error); 
    }; 
    
    stompClient.onStompError = (frame) => { 
        console.error('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']); 
        console.error('Additional details: ' + frame.body); 
    }; 
    
    stompClient.activate(); 

Broker configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketBrokerConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer  {

    @Autowired
    private HandshakeHandler handshakeHandler;
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat/");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

}

Event Listener
@Component
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketEventListener  {
    
    @Autowired
    private ChatManager chatManager;
    
     @EventListener
        private void handleSessionConnected(SessionConnectEvent event) {
         log.info("{}", event);
        }

        @EventListener
        private void handleSessionDisconnect(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
            log.info("{}", event);
        }
        
        @EventListener
        private void handleSessionSubscribe(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
            final Map<String, Object> nativeHeaders = (Map<String, Object>) 
            event.getMessage().getHeaders().get("nativeHeaders");
            final String sessionId = 
            event.getMessage().getHeaders().get("simpSessionId").toString();
            log.info("sessionId: {}", sessionId);
            log.info("subscribed destination: {}", nativeHeaders.get("destination"));
            log.info("subscribed user {}", event.getUser().getName());
            SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = 
            SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
            headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
    
            log.info("Sending reply to: {}", event.getUser().getName());
            Message message = new Message().setTo(event.getUser().getName()).setBody("hi");
            simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
            event.getUser().getName(), "/chat", message, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders()); 
        }

}

Handshake Handler
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class HandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler{

    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
            Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();           

        if (principal == null) {
            principal = new AnonymousPrincipal();

            String uniqueName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            ((AnonymousPrincipal) principal).setName(uniqueName);
            log.info("new user: {}", uniqueName);
        }

        return principal;

    }

}

Here are the logs from org.springframework.messaging=TRACE
...configuration.HandshakeHandler         : new user: 8eee251d-2777-430c-b137-a5f462d7dd8f
....s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder   : Decoded CONNECT {accept-version=[1.2,1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[10000,10000]} session=null
....s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler    : Processing CONNECT user=8eee251d-2777-430c-b137-...i.listener.WebSocketEventListener : SessionConnectEvent[GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=CONNECT, stompCommand=CONNECT, nativeHeaders={accept-version=[1.2,1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpHeartbeat=[J@7d5c7266, simpUser=AnonymousPrincipal(name=8eee251d-2777-430c-b137-a5f462d7dd8f), simpSessionId=d480e89a-813b-7776-23e0-6a0e34e9c70c}]]
...s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP CONNECTED, headers={version=[1.2], heart-beat=[0,0], user-name=[8eee251d-2777-430c-b137-a5f462d7dd8f]}
...s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder    : Decoded SUBSCRIBE {id=[sub-0], destination=[/user/chat]} session=null
..s.m.s.u.UserDestinationMessageHandler   : Translated /user/chat -> [/chat-userd480e89a-813b-7776-23e0-6a0e34e9c70c]
...w.i.listener.WebSocketEventListener    : sessionId: d480e89a-813b-7776-23e0-6a0e34e9c70c
...w.i.listener.WebSocketEventListener    : subscribed destination: [/user/chat]
...w.i.listener.WebSocketEventListener    : subscribed user 8eee251d-2777-430c-b137-a5f462d7dd8f
...websocket.chat.ChatManager             : Sending reply to: 8eee251d-2777-430c-b137-a5f462d7dd8f
..m.s.u.UserDestinationMessageHandler     : Translated /user/8eee251d-2777-430c-b137-a5f462d7dd8f/chat -> [/chat-userd480e89a-813b-7776-23e0-6a0e34e9c70c]


Trying to send an message during the subscription event is not yet at the completion of subscription so trying to send a message to user during that process means that the message is sent before the subscription is complete. When I wrapped the sending of the message in its own thread the message sends after the completion of the subscription.
